# How to change the priceScale in a similar way as barSpacing does with timeScale?

Tags: lightweight-charts

We can change the timeScale manually:

```js
chart.timeScale().applyOptions({
  barSpacing: 15
})
```

But i can`t find the same method for [priceScale](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/PriceScaleOptions).

I want to set a specific zoom/range for priceScale because the autoScale option does not meet my requirements. I already read ALL of github/stackoverflow/docs and can't understand how to reach it without reverse engineering.

If it`s impossible, please, show a code reference where I can change/add this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API to do this directly on the price scale (set visible price range).

However, you could look at [`autoscaleInfoProvider`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/next/api/interfaces/SeriesOptionsCommon#autoscaleinfoprovider) within the series options as a way to provide a different visible price range when the chart is automatically fitting the content to price scale.

If you user manually adjusts the price scale then these autoscale values will be ignored (but this is expected).